# Does something happen after the The End screen?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

After completing the final chapter, the game will loop the sleeping hat kid scene including the background music.

I have waited 20 minutes and nothing happened, expecting some reward or achievement.

Does something happen after waiting longer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Nothing happens. It's simply an end game screen. Moustache Kid will not come out the floorboards and steal your stuff.